# Netherlands census data by municipality (gemeente)

Tags: data, census, netherlands

I am looking for Dutch Census data (period 2012-2019), aggregated at the gemeente level (municipality), covering basic population statistics (number of people, gender, age, ethnicity, etc). The gemeente have codes like `GM0376`. I checked 
https://opendata.cbs.nl/statline/#/CBS/en/navigatieScherm/thema?themaNr=5610 but I can't find this kind of data.

Comment: Have you checked on the OpenData SE? Always a good place to look for this type of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

That would be the "bronhouderscode", a list of which can be found here: https://zakelijk.kadaster.nl/documents/20838/87957/BGT+Bronhouderscodes+per+1-1-2019/f0ddea62-a1a8-65b2-4816-da3b836553f8